# JSX/JavaScript syntax in Chrome

Tags: javascript, syntax-error, reactjs

This is really silly but i got a problem with Chrome (works fine in Firefox) with this syntax borrowed from an example in react-dnd component (link: https://github.com/gaearon/react-dnd/blob/master/examples/_dustbin-simple/Dustbin.js).

```
const itemDropTarget = {
    acceptDrop(component, item) {
        component.setItem(item);
    }
};
```

It trigger this error:

Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token (

Chrome doesn't like this either:

```
const DustbinSimple = React.createClass({
    render() {
```

It must be:

```
const DustbinSimple = React.createClass({
    render: function() {
```

What am i missing? Must be something really basic i don't understand.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

JSX is an extension to Javascript. To actually run it in the browser, you must run it through the [JSX Transformer](http://facebook.github.io/react/downloads.html#jsx-transformer).

Comment: You are right, i didn't specify that the code was already compiled with browserify/reactify

Answer (score 2):

I found what the problem was... 
I needed to compile JSX code using --harmony flag with reactify/browserify:

```
...
bundler.transform(["reactify", {"harmony": true}]);
...
```

Comment: Yes, if you use any ES6 features and want to run them in a browser that doesn't support them yet, you need to compile them to ES5 as well. The `harmony` flag does that. (It doesn't actually have anything to do with JSX).

Answer (score 0):

you can add parcel bundler to your project.It will automatically transform your code so the browser can understand